# SQL export to ListView using C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, listview

I have a query that selects 3 columns from a SQL table, I need to export the resulting query into a listview.  I don't need any help with the SQL setup, just how to format it into the listview.  There is where I am stuck.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

```
string sql = "select distinct pro,ds,date from dbo.Sge where date IN (select max(date) from dbo.Storage) order by project";
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source= ;Initial Catalog= ;Integrated Security= SSPI");
con.Open();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql,con);
adapter.Fill(ds);
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    for(int i=0; i< ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count; i++))
}
```

**Edit:** Sorry guys, i mentioned ListBox originally and i meant ListView. My ListView is detailed and had a column for each of my columns in my select, i just simply need the SQL export to go to the right column.

This is what I have come up with, but it doesn't add to each column, just to the first column

```
foreach (DataRow row in poplb6ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    listView1.Items.Add(row["Pro"].ToString());
    listView1.Items.Add(row["size"].ToString());
    listView1.Items.Add(row["Date"].ToString());
}
```

Comment: i understand i need Subitems, just not sure how to piece it together.

Comment: `System.Windows.Forms.FormsListView` or `System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView`? WinForms or ASP.NET?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following assumes that your ListView has columns in the order |Pro|Size|Date|

```
foreach (DataRow row in poplb6ds.Tables[0].Rows) {
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(row["Pro"].ToString());
    item.SubItems.Add(row["size"].ToString());
    item.SubItems.Add(row["Date"].ToString());
    listView1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The standaard solution would be: `listbox1.DataSource = poplb6ds;`
If you need any specific formatting, please elaborate on that.

Comment: I have a detailed view in which each need to go into the appropriate list for my listview, and i do apologize, i am using listview

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

[C# listView, how do I add items to columns 2, 3 and 4 etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473148/c-listview-how-do-i-add-items-to-columns-2-3-and-4-etc)

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `using` blocks:

   ```
   using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=;Initial Catalog= ;Integrated Security= SSPI"))
   {
       con.Open();
       using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
       {
           using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con))
           {
               adapter.Fill(ds);
           }    
       }
   }
   ```
2. Fill single table:

   ```
   DataTable dt = new DataTable(); // new DataTable("Sge"); name it if will be required
   adapter.Fill(dt);
   ```
3. Your loop has makes no sense because columns are the same for each row in the table:

   ```
   foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
   {
   }
   ```
4. Or you want to iterate thru each row and each column?

   ```
   foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
   {
       foreach (DataRow row in dt)
       {
           object value = row[column];
       }
   }
   ```