# How to add multiple items so it displays data through out columns in ListView in detailed mode using a loop?

Tags: c#, .net, listbox

I am just trying to figure out how to work this out.

So, I I have figured out how to create new column in my ListView. I have also figured out how to add an item to my ListView.

The problem is that in my code I am only adding an entry to the first columns name, the other 2 are left blank.

How do I add entry, let say column A with a1, B with a2, and C with a3?

I have browsed through some examples that I have found somewhat confusing.

**Examples for dummies preferred.**

EDIT: I have edited the question because I found out how to add individual items.

Now, how would I add individual entries using a loop? Since I am cerating each item named item1, item2, ect.. how can I do loop with this? This is what I have at this moment:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            listView1.Columns.Add("A");
            listView1.Columns.Add("B");
            listView1.Columns.Add("C");

            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem("a1");
            item.SubItems.Add("a2");
            item.SubItems.Add("a3");

            listView1.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] {item});
        }
    }
}
```

My goal is to change the display of my textbox to use ViewList. Focus on first entry. I am trying to have column PC Password, User Name, and Password, so my code example starts from scratch.

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473148/c-sharp-listview-how-do-i-add-items-to-columns-2-3-and-4-etc

Comment: @user629926: I have just read this. I have another dilemma so I have just edited the title and some content.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly what you intend to do. Do you want to end up with some kind of table display with columns for PCPassword, UserName and Password and a row for each entry? Why the choice of a ListView instead of a DataGrid or so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I get right what you would like to do.

But you can add multiple items to a ListView using a loop the following way:

Edited for a sample datareader.

```
    ListViewItem item;
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            item = new ListViewItem(reader.getString(0));
            item.SubItems.Add(reader.getString(1));
            item.SubItems.Add(reader.getString(2));

            listView1.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: First of all, what does NO mean in here? Second, what if additional data is added for example datareader? this won't work.

Comment: @HelpNeeder NO means the number of the items you would like to add, sorry for not clarifying that. The for loop and its condition was just an example, I don't really know what kind of data are you working on, or from where do you have it. You could use instead of the for a `while(reader.Read())` loop.

Comment: Precisely I want to use datareader. The problem is that how do I work so item name changes?

Comment: @HelpNeeder I edited my answer to use a datareader. (Note that I don't know your datasource, so I just used `getString(0)`,..). What do you mean by changing item names? You would like to use different variables to store the items, like `ListViewItem item1`, `ListViewItem item2`, ... ?

Comment: This might actually work. +1 for now. And if it will work with my program I'll accept :) Thanks!