# Add item to Listview control

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a `listview` in c# with three columns and the view is details. I need to add a item to each specific column but I am having a hard time with this. I have tried several things. Here is what I got so far. Thanks for any help in advance.

```
// Add the pet to our listview
ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
lvi.SubItems.Add(pet.Name);
lvi.SubItems.Add(pet.Type);
lvi.SubItems.Add(pet.Age);

listView.Items.Add(lvi);
```

[image: Here is the result]

Comment: Have you checked [this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473148/c-sharp-listview-how-do-i-add-items-to-columns-2-3-and-4-etc

Answer (score 87, accepted):

I have done it like this and it seems to work:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] row = { textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text };
        var listViewItem = new ListViewItem(row); 
        listView1.Items.Add(listViewItem);
    }
}
```

Comment: remember to set property listView1.View = Details;

Answer (score 16):

The first column actually refers to Text Field:

```
  // Add the pet to our listview
    ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
    lvi.text = pet.Name;
    lvi.SubItems.Add(pet.Type);
    lvi.SubItems.Add(pet.Age);

    listView.Items.Add(lvi);
```

Or you can use the [Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.subitems.aspx)

```
 ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(pet.Name);
 lvi.SubItems.Add(pet.Type);
 ....
```

Answer (score 4):

Add items:

```
arr[0] = "product_1";
arr[1] = "100";
arr[2] = "10";
itm = new ListViewItem(arr);
listView1.Items.Add(itm);
```

Retrieve items:

```
productName = listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text;
price = listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text;
quantity = listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[2].Text;
```

[source code](http://csharp.net-informations.com/gui/cs-listview.htm)

Answer (score 3):

Simple one, just do like this..

```
ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(pet.Name);
    lvi.SubItems.Add(pet.Type);
    lvi.SubItems.Add(pet.Age);
    listView.Items.Add(lvi);
```

Answer (score 1):

- Very Simple

  ```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
      item.SubItems.Add(textBox2.Text);
      item.SubItems.Add(textBox3.Text);
      item.SubItems.Add(textBox4.Text);
      listView1.Items.Add(item);
      textBox2.Clear();
      textBox3.Clear();
      textBox4.Clear();
  }
  ```
- You can also Do this stuff...

  ```
      ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
      item.SubItems.Add("Santosh");
      item.SubItems.Add("26");
      item.SubItems.Add("India");
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The ListView control uses the Items collection to [add items to listview](http://www.kettic.com/winforms_ui/csharp_guide/listview_design_time_add_item.shtml) in the control and is able to customize items.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Source: Youtube</sub>

[C# ListView item add, modify, insert, delete](https://youtu.be/hgJZJOBKs8k)

```cs
    string[] mItem = new string[] { textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text } ;

    var listItem = new ListViewItem(mItem) ;

    listView1.Items.Add(listItem) ;
```