# Listview c# instead of listbox

Tags: c#, windows, forms, listview

I have a `List<Student>` where for every student 4 properties.

At the moment I'm using this:

```
listStudents = new List<Student>();

foreach (Student s in listStudents)
{
   listbox1.Items.Add(s);
}
```

But it shows the 4 properties next to each other.

I did some research to sort the properties in columns, and found `listview`.

Can anyone explain me how can i do this?

I tried to `add columns` to the collection of the `listview`, but it still didn't work...

I tried also it:

```
listStudents = new List<Student>();

foreach (Student s in listStudents)
{
   listview.Items.Add(s);
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I just want the 4 propertys for each student in different columns.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951704/add-item-to-listview-control

Comment: I actually like listview instead of listbox. It can look fancier with not much fancy code. It can look like a grid. Add headers/columns to it, then add items. I think, you need to add each particular column value separately.

Answer (score 0):

First set the column names (you can do this with the graphical designer):

```
listView1.Columns.Add("col 1");
listView1.Columns.Add("col 2");
listView1.Columns.Add("col 3");
listView1.Columns.Add("col 4");
```

and then add rows (I assume here that your properties are strings):

```
foreach(Student s in listStudents){
    listView1.Items.Add(new string[]{
        s.Property1, s.Property2, s.Property3, s.Property4
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            List<Student> StudentsList = new List<Student>();
            Student StuObj = new Student();
            StuObj.ID = 1;
            StuObj.age = 23;
            StuObj.name = "ROCK";
            StudentsList.Add(StuObj);
            foreach (Student s in StudentsList)
            {
                string[] array = { s.ID.ToString(), s.age.ToString(), s.name.ToString()};
                var items = listView1.Items;
                foreach (var value in array)
                {
                    items.Add(value);
                }

            }
```