# How to show all data results to listview?

Tags: c#

I have a code here showing the data from sqldatabase to listview when searching.

```
 int flag = 0;

        connectionstatus();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT *FROM SampleDatabase WHERE IdNo=@IdNo", conn);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@IdNo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtIdNo.Text;
        SqlDataReader objRead = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        lvlist.Items.Clear();
        while (objRead.Read())
        {
            if ((txtIdNo.Text) == (objRead["IdNo"].ToString()))
            {
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (flag == 1)
        {
            ListViewItem list = new ListViewItem(basa["FID"].ToString());
            list.SubItems.Add(objRead["FullName"].ToString());
            list.SubItems.Add(objRead["Age"].ToString());
            list.SubItems.Add(objRead["Gender"].ToString());
            list.SubItems.Add(objRead["Relationship"].ToString());
            list.SubItems.Add(objRead["SkillnOccupation"].ToString());
            lvlist.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] { list });
        }
```

My problem is that when im searching and the database have data with the same IdNo it only shows 1 result.  How can i show all the results that has the same IdNo? Can you guys help me out in this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe it is a fish

Comment: oh sorry it should be objRead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the item population code inside the loop:

```
    while (objRead.Read())
    {
        ListViewItem list = new ListViewItem(basa["FID"].ToString());
        list.SubItems.Add(objRead["FullName"].ToString());
        list.SubItems.Add(objRead["Age"].ToString());
        list.SubItems.Add(objRead["Gender"].ToString());
        list.SubItems.Add(objRead["Relationship"].ToString());
        list.SubItems.Add(objRead["SkillnOccupation"].ToString());
        lvlist.Items.Add(list);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your last line with this. Seems like you're making two ListViewItems for every item? See if it helps, then look here.

[Add item to Listview control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951704/add-item-to-listview-control)

```
lvlist.Items.Add(list);
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but still it only shows 1 result.

Comment: @user3416518 And you're positive the data returned doesn't only show 1 result due to the flag? When you step through the code, what happens with your second result?