# Count numbers and add them to listview

Tags: c#, count

i want to know how to add counted numbers from an array to a an listview.

First: I'm really new to C#!

So... Every 5 minutes my application is generating 5 random numbers within a range (1-100). Lets say the random numbers are now: 5, 19, 55, 74 and 81.

I have an ListView on my Form with 2 colums "Number | Count".

In the first column are all numbers from my range (1-100) and the second coulmn should count how often numbers are generated. So in the second column my application should add them to the listview (count).

Number | Count

1. 1 | 0
2. 2 | 0
3. 3 | 0
4. 4 | 0
5. 5 | 1
6. [...]
7. 20 | 0
8. 19 | 1
9. 21 | 0
10. [...]
11. 54 |0
12. 55 | 1
13. 56 | 0
14. [...]

And now: Every 5 minutes there are 5 new random numbers. Now count them up by 1 too.

I hope you can understand what i want to do here.
Maybe someone can help me out. I dont know how to do that.

Best regards and thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like homework should get done by stackoverflow community. I throw in some key words: loop, 1 to 100, array or dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing that your list view is already filled with the value you shown, the only thing you have to do is getting the corresponding rows of the number that you generated and increment the counter

You could do that.

```
        int value = int.Parse(listView1.Items[index].SubItems[1].Text) +1;
        listView1.Items.RemoveAt(index);
        listView1.Items.Insert(index,
            new ListViewItem(new[]
            {
                index.ToString(),
                value.ToString()
            }));
```

If your problem is that you don't know how to add value in your list view, take a look at this post: [Add item to Listview control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951704/add-item-to-listview-control)