# Add ListView item to a simple list?

Tags: c#, listview, uwp

Beginner here. I am trying to add a simple item to the ListView control that I am having. After clicking the + button, I will type a value and I would like that value to be added to the list, similar to the first item in the screenshot.

How do I 'create' a new item and save it in the ListView control?

There isn't really any code just yet. Trying to figure out how to approach this.

[image]

Comment: What is your code so far? Can you add what you have tried up to this point?

Comment: Check this answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951704/add-item-to-listview-control

Comment: `ListView.Items.Add(list_view_item);`

Answer (score 1):

If you add the first ListViewItem by the XAML, you should be able to use the `ListView.Items.Add` method to add the `ListViewItem` to the `ListView`.

For example:

```
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
TextBlock mytext = new TextBlock();
mytext.Text = "Item 2";
item.Content = mytext;
MyListView.Items.Add(item);
```

We can also bind the Collection to the ListView, then we can add new item to the Collection that the item will be added to the ListView.

For example:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ListView Name="MyListView">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="Button_Click">click</Button>
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private ObservableCollection<Item> Items;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
        Item item1 = new Item();
        item1.Name = "Item 1";
        Items.Add(item1);
        MyListView.ItemsSource = Items;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Item item2 = new Item();
        item2.Name = "Item 2";
        Items.Add(item2);
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```