# Add item to Listview from function

Tags: c#, listview, listviewitem

I'm trying to add a row in my listView1. How do i do this in another function?

I was reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951704/add-item-to-listview-control) post. And they want me to add it directly in a button function. I don't want to do that.

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    keyword();
}

public static void keyword()
{
    string country = "";
    string key = "1070";

    //Goto GetHtmlAsync
    GetHtmlAsync(key, country);
}

public static async void GetHtmlAsync(string key, string country)
{
    //GetHtmlAsync
    var url = "https://www.test.com/search?county=" + country + "&q=" + key;

    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var html = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);

    var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
    htmlDocument.LoadHtml(html);

    //This is grabbed from HtmlDocument (list)
    var id = "58756";
    var seller = "Test";
    var product = "GTX 1070";
    var betTime = "10:10";
    var price = "100";
    var shipping = "4";

    string[] row = { id, seller, product, betTime, price + shipping, url };
    var listViewItem = new ListViewItem(row);
    listView1.Items.Add(listViewItem);
}
```

I expect it to add a row in the listView1 here `listView1.Items.Add(listViewItem);`, but i get an error message saying

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Form1.listView1'

Comment: Remove `static` from `public static async`

Comment: Or remove `static async` which you don't need any of it... you are not `await` *ing* anything...

Comment: I think he will add something related to async (as function name says)

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ This thing `string[] row = { id, seller, product, betTime, price + shipping, link };` might come from http client,

Comment: @fhnaseer if it did then why passing all the arguments? I am not saying I don't agree somewhat, but the current structure I am seeing is it's not async and nothing utilizes an asynchronous operation. Yes, we can make assumptions, but I prefer not when user *only* shows part of code in question.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. I have some stuff in my function that uses static and async, removed it here cus i did not think those matter. When i remove the sttatic it workes, but then i get another error cus i need the static for other stuff inside the function

Comment: @SablyTv, IMHO as well `price + shipping` you are trying to do a mathematical operation on strings, I would strongly change the type if that is your intentions. `but then i get another error cus i need the static for other stuff inside the function`, this is why you post *all* relevant code, we can't guess what you have.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ, I know, when it's more like 900 + 120, when 900 = price and 120 = shipping. `, this is why you post all relevant code, we can't guess what you have` i did not know that was relevent. My bad, ill update

Comment: The problem you *had* should be resolved, but you mentioned you have another issue, `but then i get another error cus i need the static for other stuff inside the function`. If this is the case, update your post so we can better assist you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So according to your requirements try this.

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    keyword();
}
// Non static so that you can access ListView1
public void keyword()
{
    string country = "";
    string key = "1070";

    //Goto GetHtmlAsync
    GetHtmlAsync(key, country);
}
// Non static
public async void GetHtmlAsync(string key, string country)
{
    //GetHtmlAsync
    var url = "https://www.test.com/search?county=" + country + "&q=" + key;

    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var html = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);

    var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
    htmlDocument.LoadHtml(html);

    //This is grabbed from HtmlDocument (list)
    var id = "58756";
    var seller = "Test";
    var product = "GTX 1070";
    var betTime = "10:10";
    var price = "100";
    var shipping = "4";

    string[] row = { id, seller, product, betTime, price + shipping, url };
    var listViewItem = new ListViewItem(row);
    listView1.Items.Add(listViewItem);
}
```