# Merge an array with a ListView

Tags: c#, arrays, forms, visual-studio, listview

I've been trying to finish a project of mine studying C# for now and have been encountered with a problem.
The task is to create ill or healthy animals and separate them to different arrays.
Everything worked fine until I tried to merge between an array to a `ListView`.

What I want to do is to use the array's information and to insert it into the list's columns, which I don't know how to do.
It's purpose is to make each array communicate with the list, when you add or remove animals from any array, it deletes the specific animal from the list, and same thing about adding animals.

This is what I've been trying to do but it is not a good job. I need to collect the info from the array and not from the textboxes.

```
private void btnAddStack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtCode.Text == "Example: 1234")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Fill in animal's code in order to proceed", "Error");
        txtCode.Focus();
        return;
    }

    if (txtName.Text == "Example: Lion")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Fill in animal's name in order to proceed", "Error");
        txtName.Focus();
        return;
    }

    if (txtWeight.Text == "Example: 100")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Fill in animal's weight in order to proceed", "Error");
        txtWeight.Focus();
        return;
    }

    if (rbFemale.Checked == false && rbMale.Checked == false)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Fill in animal's gender in order to proceed", "Error");
        return;
    }

    if (rbNoMarine.Checked == false && rbYesMarine.Checked == false)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Choose if the animal is marine or not in order to proceed", "Error");
        return;
    }

    btnTakeCareSt.Enabled = true;
    service.addNewAnimal(int.Parse(txtCode.Text), txtName.Text, float.Parse(txtWeight.Text), CheckMarine(), CheckUrgent(), CheckGender());
    lvStack.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new[] {txtName.Text, txtCode.Text, txtWeight.Text, BoolToString(), CheckMarine().ToString()}));
}
```

Comment: your question is not so clear, but can you check this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951704/add-item-to-listview-control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size of the Array is fixed, you cannot add or remove its items dynamically. Maybe using List is a better choice.

Here I have a class `Student` for test, and you can define a List to store its instances.

```
/// <summary>
/// Student class for test
/// </summary>
class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Define a list in Form class:

```
// Define a list to store students
List<Student> students = new List<Student>() { new Student { Name = "A", Age = 10 },
                         new Student { Name = "B", Age = 9 },
                         new Student { Name = "C", Age = 14 } };
```

Then you can refer to the following code to store the items in list to ListView.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listView1.View = View.Details;

    this.listView1.Columns.Add("Name", 120, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
    this.listView1.Columns.Add("Age", 120, HorizontalAlignment.Left);

    this.listView1.BeginUpdate();

    for (int i = 0; i < students.Count; i++)
    {
        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
        lvi.Text = students[i].Name;
        lvi.SubItems.Add(students[i].Age.ToString());
        this.listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
    }

    this.listView1.EndUpdate();
}
```

To add a new item, please refer to:

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Add a new student named "D" and age is 17;
    string name = "D";
    int age = 17;
    // Add new student to list and ListView
    Student student = new Student() { Name = name, Age = age };
    students.Add(student);
    ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
    lvi.Text = student.Name;
    lvi.SubItems.Add(student.Age.ToString());
    this.listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
}
```

As to remove a specific item, you can use:

```
private void btnRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Remove the student whose name is "B"
    string name = "B";
    // Remove the data in list
    var found = students.Find(x => x.Name == name);
    if (found != null) students.Remove(found);

    // Remove the item in ListView
    ListViewItem foundItem = this.listView1.FindItemWithText(name, true, 0);
    if (foundItem != null)
    {
        listView1.Items.Remove(foundItem);
    }
}
```

Comment: @ZivHausler If this is helpful for you, please click "√" to mark it as an answer.