# ListView Columns

Tags: c#, .net, listview

I have 2 columns in a `ListView`. My "C:\file.txt" looks like this:

```
1;aaa 
2;bbb
3;ccc 
4;ddd
```

and so on. (each number and text in separate line)
My code:

```
FileStream spis = File.Open("C:\\file.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
StreamReader yaRead = new StreamReader(spis);
string yaView = yaRead.ReadToEnd();
yaRead.Close();
spis.Close();
String[] yaArray = yaView.Split(new char[] {';'});
foreach (string ya in yaArray)
{
    listView1.Items.Add(ya);
}
```

It results

```
1
aaa
bbb
(...)
```

...in first column and nothing in second column. Please help me fix it.

Comment: Despite adding an answer, I just realised this is partially answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473148/c-sharp-listview-how-do-i-add-items-to-columns-2-3-and-4-etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add columns to a list view via the SubItems property of a [ListViewItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.aspx).

The simplest way is to do something like:

```
ListViewItem newItem = new ListViewItem("1");
newItem.SubItems.Add("aaa");
listView1.Items.Add(newItem);
```

If we take your example, we can simply do something like the following:

```
string[] yaArray = yaView.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

This will give you an array that looks like:

```
[1;aaa]
[2;bbb]
[3;ccc]
[4;ddd]
```

We've split based on the new line rather than the semi-colon.

Then it's simply a matter of doing the following:

```
foreach(string lineItem in yaArray)
{
  string[] listViewRow = lineItem.Split(new string[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.None); //Now we split on the semi colon to give us each item
  ListViewItem newItem = new ListViewItem(listViewRow[0]);
  newItem.SubItems.Add(listViewRow[1];
  listView1.Items.Add(newItem);
}
```

That should give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Please, add SUBitems to list

```
foreach(var line in File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\file.txt"))
{
  listView1.Items.Add(line.Split(';'));
}
```