# Missing ListView.Columns in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, compiler-errors, listviewitem

I'm writing an application with a ListView in C# WPF. I was wondering if I was missing a reference of something, because I get this error all the time:

> 'System.Windows.Controls.ListView' does not contain a definition for 'Columns' and no extension method 'Columns' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.ListView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

It's not only with MyListview.Colums but also when I want to add a multi-column item to my ListView, for example by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473148/c-sharp-listview-how-do-i-add-items-to-columns-2-3-and-4-etc/).
`MyListView.Items.Add("Column1Text").SubItems.AddRange(row1);` This gives me the same error for SubItems

It's hard for me to explain, so if something isn't clear you can ask.

**Edit: With a lot of help from you and some Googling skills I found a solution. My XAML code:**

```
<Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="MyListView"
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView x:Name="MyGridView">
                <GridViewColumn Header="#" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Number}" Width="24" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Song" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Song}" Width="390" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

and here is how to add an item:

```
        MyListView.Items.Add(new { Number = 1, Song = "My first song" });
        MyListView.Items.Add(new { Number = 2, Song = "My second song" });
```

This was my first time working with bindings, but I learned a lot!

Comment: You don't have to explain it, just post your code.  We can't fix syntax errors from a verbal explanation.  ListView doesn't have a Columns property.  Check the documentation:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listview.aspx

Comment: Edit your question, and put the code in there.  It's much more difficult to read as a comment.

Comment: @ H.B. I just found out I mixed up some XAML and WinForms code, SubItems is Winforms code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

afaik, GridView has columns, ListView does not.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridview.aspx):

> Represents a view mode that displays data items in columns for a ListView control.

Comment: You were right, that partly solves my question. However I am still not able to add multi column item to my gridview.

Comment: @P1nGu1n: Why do you add columns programmatically? Can't you do this in XAML?

Comment: @P1nGu1n: Also see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridview.columns.aspx): `myGridView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn());`.

Comment: I know how to do it in XAML, but I read it's also possible to do it programmatically, but I couldn't make it work. Adding columns works, but adding items still doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: @P1nGu1n: Create a grid view, add columns, add items. That should work.

Comment: Adding items in a multi column gridview doesn't work for me. When trying this `ListViewPlaylist.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new[] { "1", "2", "3", "4" }));` it gives me this error: `'System.Windows.Controls.ListViewItem' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments`

Comment: @P1nGu1n: [Quick search](https://www.google.com/search?q=wpf+add+gridview+programmatically+site:stackoverflow.com) gave a number of very useful posts how to add columns and rows programmatically. Seems that you have WinForms background, but you need to remember that WPF has different API and approaches. WPF GridView's column uses Binding to read a property from a row.