# listview c#: how to add items to columns other than the first

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

My question is an exact duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473148/c-sharp-listview-how-do-i-add-items-to-columns-2-3-and-4-etc):
"To add items to column 1 in my listView control (Winform) I'm using listView1.Items.Add, this works fine but how do I add items to columns 2 and 3 etc? "

Lots of similar Q&A elsewhere, but none of them talk about how to add items using the WinForms interactive listView builder as opposed to coding it directly.  I know how to code it, but since you can add items to the first column using the builder, I assume there must be a way to do it for the other columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click on the ListView and select "Edit Items..." to get the ListViewItem Collection Editor.

Select a ListViewItem (or click Add to add one and then select it).  In the properties pane find SubItems in the Data category.  Click on the "..." button to open the ListViewSubItem Collection Editor and you can add sub-items, which appear in the columns after the first.

You need to set the Text property of your ListViewItems and ListViewSubItems if you want to see anything.

Comment: Doing what you suggest works, but it begins adding just one item to each column, moving horizontally, instead of vertically (as it does when you add items to Column One.)

Comment: It's not a spreadsheet.  Conceptually, things that appear in columns two, three, etc. are properties of the thing in column one.  It doesn't make any sense to have 5 items in column two but only 3 in column one.  What are the last two items in column two properties of?

Comment: Oh, you're right.  Makes more sense it would add them horizontally.  BTW, once I add these and then select "View Code", shouldn't the code show up back in the form1.cs tab?  I had to run the app, and *then* it showed up!

Comment: The changes appear immediately in Form1.Designer.cs.  I don't see any change in Form1.cs.  Which is what I'd expect.  Unless you're using a *really* old version of Visual Studio.

Comment: No, I'm using VS2010 Premium.  I suspect I have a setting wrong somewhere else, because I am getting screwy behavior elsewhere.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's very important also to use "listView1.FullRowSelect = true"... otherwise only column 1 is clickable.

Answer (score 0):

I think (not sure) that most simple way is to add array of strings, and the list view knows the column according to the array index.