# ObjectListView does not display

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to use ObjectListView, but fail on something that is supposed to be very simple. This is my code:

```
List<Book> books = new List<Book>();
Book book = new Book();
book.name = "book 1";
book.author = "author 1";
books.Add(book);
book = new Book();
book.name = "book 2";
book.author = "author 2";
books.Add(book);
this.objectListView1.SetObjects(books);
```

It seems simple, it compiles OK, but nothing is displayed!

Comment: why you create two instance of class Book

Comment: Try to understanding ListView in WINFORM

[clicl] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473148/c-sharp-listview-how-do-i-add-items-to-columns-2-3-and-4-etc