# How to submit textbox text to listView in matching column in separate form

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

So I have `Form1` and `Form2`. `Form1` has `listView1` inside which has 3 columns. `Form2` has 3 textbox's which hold text. On `Form2` there is a button to submit the text to the matching columns of `Form1`.

How would I get this to happen?

This may not make sense and I will help make sense if that's the case.

Comment: Is `Form2` always open, or is it a modal window that you show only when entering/editing data?

Comment: Form2 opens with a button click event on Form1. Form2 closes after the info is sent to Form1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be to set up public properties for the text values in `Form2`. When you submit the data you apply the textbox values to these properties, and then you can retrieve them from the `Form2` object in `Form1`. Here's an example:

Form2:

```
public string Name { get; set;}

private void buttonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Name = txtbxName.Text;
    Close();
}
```

Form1:

```
var entryForm = new Form2();
entryForm.ShowDialog();

var text = entryForm.Name;
// Do whatever you want with `text`
```

**EDIT:** If you need help with inserting the data into the `ListView` object I can give an example for that as well.

**EDIT 2:** Let's assume that you have three variables containing the values you want to add to the view: `name`, `age`, `sex`. You should have some sort of unique ID value assigned to each record, so we'll also add an `id` variable.

With those populated you can add a new record to your `ListView` like so:

```
ListViewItem parent = listView1.Items.Add(id);
parent.SubItems.Add(name);
parent.SubItems.Add(age.ToString());
parent.SubItems.Add(sex);
```

Comment: So far everything is working! If you could help me put it in to listView that would be great! :)

Comment: So I've been giving it a go and it only puts all the items in the first column. How would I go about matching each textbox with its matching column?

Comment: @ZacVoicheq - When referencing a specific problem like items being added to only one column, it helps to add the relevant code to your question. Hopefully my example solves your particular issue.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be

1) On button_click call form1.show().
2) create another method which takes three textbox value and binds to listbox. For reference use this link for binding: [C# listView, how do I add items to columns 2, 3 and 4 etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473148/c-sharp-listview-how-do-i-add-items-to-columns-2-3-and-4-etc)