# Put text into 3 columns

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have 3 columns in ListView: `ID`, `Title` and `Link`. How I can put some text in all 3 columns?
If i write:

```
listView1.Items.Add(Regex.Match(node.Attributes["id"].Value, @"\d+").Value + 
      Environment.NewLine);
```

it puts text only in first column(`ID`).

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# listView, how do I add items to columns 2, 3 and 4 etc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473148/c-sharp-listview-how-do-i-add-items-to-columns-2-3-and-4-etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] {"ID String Value ", "Title String Value", "Link String Value"}));
```

Comment: Also, you can use other overloads of new ListViewItem to create items with different icons etc.