# Iteratively add ListViewItems to multiple columns

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a ListView with two columns specified in the design view and I'm trying to add two lists of records to their respective columns, but I'm struggling to get the lists in the right place.

I've tried several approaches, and have come closest with this:

```
listViewFilterDescription.View = View.Details;

ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem();
for (int i = 0; i < recordSet.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    item1.SubItems.Add(recordSet.Rows[i]["description"].ToString());
}

ListViewItem item2 = new ListViewItem();
for (int i = 0; i < recordSet.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    item2.SubItems.Add(recordSet.Rows[i]["definition"].ToString());
}

listViewFilterDescription.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] { item1, item2 });
```

And while this adds all of the contents of the for loops to the two ListViewItems, it actually only adds the first record of each loop to the ListView, and it adds it to the second column only:

```
Column 1  |Column 2
==========|==========
          |ForLoop1(1)
          |ForLoop2(1)
```

How can I get it to look like this?:

```
Column 1     |Column 2
=============|=============
ForLoop1(1)  |ForLoop2(1)
ForLoop1(2)  |ForLoop2(2)
ForLoop1(3)  |ForLoop2(3)
```

Comment: Possible duplication of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473148/c-sharp-listview-how-do-i-add-items-to-columns-2-3-and-4-etc?lq=1

Comment: can you try this
listViewFilterDescription.Items.Add("Column1Text").SubItems.AddRange(item1);
listViewFilterDescription.Items.Add("Column2Text").SubItems.AddRange(item2);

Comment: @FrancisSaul Thanks I tried this, but it gives me an error: the best overloaded match for ListViewSubItemcollection.AddRange(string[]) has some invalid arguments, despite converting item1/item2 to strings

Comment: Hi duney, can you try this

ListViewItem[] item = {item1,item2};
for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
ListViewItem myItem = item[i];
listViewFilterDescription.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] { myItem});
}

Answer (score 0):

can you try this approach to see if able to add items in array format. thanks

//Add columns first

```
    listViewFilterDescription.Columns.Add("Id");
    listViewFilterDescription.Columns.Add("Name");
```

//Add items[] to your list

```
var item1 = new ListViewItem(new[] {"Car", "Boat", "AirPlane"});
var item2 = new ListViewItem(new[] {"Sheila", "Catherine", "Franz"});
listViewFilterDescription.Items.Add(item1);
listViewFilterDescription.Items.Add(item2);

OR 
    ListViewItem[] item = {item1,item2}; 
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++){ ListViewItem myItem = item[i];
    listViewFilterDescription.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] { myItem}); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this doesn't answer your problem on adding items on 1st column on the first loop, but this will make the same output as you like

```
  for (int i = 0; i < recordSet.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        ListViewItem item1 = item1.SubItems.Add(recordSet.Rows[i]["description"].ToString());
        item1.SubItems.Add(recordSet.Rows[i]["definition"].ToString());
        listViewFilterDescription.Items.Add(lvi);
    }
```