# How can i add items to listView to specific tab?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
private int numberofallmessages = 0;
private int countMsg = 0;

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    OpenPop.Pop3.Pop3Client PopClient = new OpenPop.Pop3.Pop3Client();
    PopClient.Connect("mail", 110, false);
    PopClient.Authenticate("me", "me",
    OpenPop.Pop3.AuthenticationMethod.UsernameAndPassword);
    int messageCount = PopClient.GetMessageCount();
    numberofallmessages = messageCount;
    allMessages = new List<OpenPop.Mime.Message>(messageCount);
    for (int i = messageCount; i > 0; i--)
    {
        if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending == true)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            return;
        }
        allMessages.Add(PopClient.GetMessage(i));
        int nProgress = (messageCount - i + 1) * 100 / messageCount;
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(nProgress, PopClient.GetMessageCount().ToString() + "/" + i);
    }
    PopClient.Disconnect();        
}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    pbt.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    pbt.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%";
    pbt.Invalidate();
    label8.Text = e.UserState.ToString();
    label8.Visible = true;
    lstMail.Items.Add(allMessages[countMsg].Headers.Subject + "     " + allMessages[countMsg].Headers.DateSent);
    countMsg += 1;
}
```

In the ProgressChanged event i'm adding the items to the listView(lstMail).

```
lstMail.Items.Add(allMessages[countMsg].Headers.Subject + "     " + allMessages[countMsg].Headers.DateSent);
```

But this line will keep adding also the DateSent to the first tab and not to the date tab:
[image]

There is a subject tab and a date tab and i want that the part

```
allMessages[countMsg].Headers.DateSent
```

Will be under the date tab.

Comment: By 'tab', do you mean 'column'? If so, see [C# listView, how do I add items to columns 2, 3 and 4 etc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473148/c-sharp-listview-how-do-i-add-items-to-columns-2-3-and-4-etc])

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger to step thru the code, or are you just running it and hoping for things to work as you might have hoped..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
lstMail.Items.Add(allMessages[countMsg].Headers.Subject + "     " + allMessages[countMsg].Headers.DateSent);
```

To:

```
lstMail.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[]
{
    "",                                                    //From Column
    allMessages[countMsg].Headers.Subject,                 //Subject Column
    allMessages[countMsg].Headers.DateSent.ToString()      //Date Column
}));
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is the standard way of adding items to columns in a listView.

```
ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem("Something");
item1.SubItems.Add("SubItem1a");
item1.SubItems.Add("SubItem1b");
item1.SubItems.Add("SubItem1c");

ListViewItem item2 = new ListViewItem("Something2");
item2.SubItems.Add("SubItem2a");
item2.SubItems.Add("SubItem2b");
item2.SubItems.Add("SubItem2c");

ListViewItem item3 = new ListViewItem("Something3");
item3.SubItems.Add("SubItem3a");
item3.SubItems.Add("SubItem3b");
item3.SubItems.Add("SubItem3c");

ListView1.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] {item1,item2,item3});
```

Also see:
[C# listView, how do I add items to columns 2, 3 and 4 etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473148/c-sharp-listview-how-do-i-add-items-to-columns-2-3-and-4-etc)