# Throw ID and its information into listview

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I got multiline textbox and ListView
textbox contains :

[1000]
name=John
number0=78569987

[1001]
name=Sara
number0=89768980
number1=77897545

---

[image]

---

```
TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text.Replace("[", "this what i want")

Dim lines As New List(Of String)
lines = TextBox2.Lines.ToList
Dim FilterText = "this what i want"
For i As Integer = lines.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
    If Not Regex.IsMatch(lines(i), FilterText) Then
        lines.RemoveAt(i)
    End If
Next
TextBox2.Lines = lines.ToArray
TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text.Replace("this what i want", "")
TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text.Replace("]", "")

ListBox1.Items.AddRange(TextBox2.Lines)

For Each x As String In ListBox1.Items
    Dim II As New ListViewItem
    II.Text = x
    ListView1.Items.Add(II)
Next
```

I cant use the same way to insert numbers and names because some ids contain number0 number 1 and some contain only number 0 ,, so how can I insert their numbers ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mind sharing the screenshots for better explanation? *Looks confusing...*

Comment: this is what I mean http://i.epvpimg.com/VyGge.jpg

Comment: You want to copy text present in textbox to listview? why 2 step approach? Also, why are you replacing `[` with `this what i want`, can't you use if directly?

Comment: I dunno how to select Information under ID to get them in the ListView  , thats why I used this long way to get all IDs .. im using multilined textbox as a RichTextBox btw.

Comment: Where is your data in RichTextBox coming from?

Comment: Ini file which a 3rd app created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the below code with comments. You might have to modify slightly to fit the data.
Check [this question and it's linked questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473148/c-sharp-listview-how-do-i-add-items-to-columns-2-3-and-4-etc) for similar thing.

**Edit**: Note that this only copies from rows in richtextbox to different columns in listview, so it will work for the examples you provided. I hope you can refine this logic to account for specific columns as per the data coming in the richtextbox.

```
Dim lines As New List(Of String)
lines = TextBox2.Lines.ToList

'Add 1st row to the listview
ListView1.Items.Add(New ListViewItem())

'Use Counter to determine row#
Dim j As Integer = 0

'Loop through the items
For i As Integer = 0 To lines.Count - 1
    'Check if it's 1st item i.e. ID and add as text (i.e. at Index 0)
    If lines(i).StartsWith("[") Then
        ListView1.Items(j).Text = lines(i).Substring(1, lines(i).Length - 2)

    'Check if contains other columns with attributes
    ElseIf lines(i).Contains("=") Then
        ListView1.Items(j).SubItems.Add(lines(i).Substring(lines(i).IndexOf("=") + 1))

    'Check if it's an empty record, and add new row to listview
    Else
        j = j + 1
        ListView1.Items.Add(New ListViewItem())
    End If
Next
```

Comment: There is a little bug  but yea this is what im looking for .. thanks

Comment: Right, it might break if the data is not coming sequentially, i.e. number0 is missing but number1 is provided, but you can modify the if else and make it mode granular checks as per the actual data. Let me know if you get stuck.