# how to print the contents of a 2D array to a listView called listViewOutput in a table like format?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, listview

I have to put categories (Film/ TV) as a row and awards(Comedy, drama etc) in a column. The user inputs the name of the film or tv series into a textbox called TBseriesName and selects category with a combo box called comboBoxCategory and uses a listBox to select which award the user wants to give called listBoxAwards.
I want it displayed like this in the listView:

```
  Comedy   Drama  Animation  Actor  Actress Foreign Language
```

TV  :
Film:

This is my attempt:

```
enter code here

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;



namespace The_Woodberry_Awards
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string[,] selection = new string[7, 2];
        string[] category = {"Film","TV"};
        string[] award = { "Comedy", "Drama", "Animation", "Actor", "Actress", "Foreign Language", "Special Effects" };

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBoxCategory.Items.Add("Film");
                comboBoxCategory.Items.Add("TV");
        }

        private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //declare and store user inputs
            int colPosition;
            int rowPosition;


            string seriesName;
            seriesName = TBseriesName.Text;
            rowPosition = listBoxAwards.SelectedIndex;
            colPosition = comboBoxCategory.SelectedIndex;
            selection[rowPosition, colPosition] = seriesName; 
        }

        private void listBoxAwards_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void buttonClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listViewOutput.Clear();

        }

        private void buttonDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           ListView.ColumnHeaderCollection col = new              ListView.ColumnHeaderCollection(listViewOutput);
            col.Add("Comedy ", 60, HorizontalAlignment.Right);
            col.Add("Drama ", 60, HorizontalAlignment.Right);
            col.Add("Animation ", 60, HorizontalAlignment.Right);
                   col.Add("Actress ", 60, HorizontalAlignment.Right);
                 col.Add("Foreign Language  ", 60, HorizontalAlignment.Right);
                col.Add("Special Effects ", 60, HorizontalAlignment.Right); 
               ListViewItem row = new ListViewItem();
                 ListViewItem column = new ListViewItem();
               //display column headers 
               for (int i = 0; i < category.Length; i++)
                {
                    row = listViewOutput.Items.Add(category[i]);

                }
```

This is what it shows at the moment when I run the program but I'm not show about how to leave space between each category in column or how to display name of show or movie 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AY7Y.png)

Comment: So you want to know how to increase the space between each column, and how to fill your table with the data?

Comment: Yeah just spacing and fill in with what users have entered in text box

Comment: To increase the space between the columns the only thing that comes into my mind is to increase the width of the columns. And to fill your listview [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473148/c-sharp-listview-how-do-i-add-items-to-columns-2-3-and-4-etc) should work. You only have to save the user input in a variable. I hope I understood you right.