# import list with columns to listview winforms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

Hi I recently picked up C# and have gone through a couple tutorials but I definitely still have a lot to learn especially by doing, so apologies in advance if I have set this up incorrectly or am not going about this an efficient way.

So as the title states, I am trying to import a list with columns into a listview.  More specifically, a class with strings into a listview.  (I am still new to all this so let me know if there is a better way of going about this.)
I think I know how to manually add listview items to columns based on this post [C# listView, how do I add items to columns 2, 3 and 4 etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473148/c-sharp-listview-how-do-i-add-items-to-columns-2-3-and-4-etc)
What I have now is using `lstViewPrinters.Items.Add(_printerlist[i].ToString());` but this adds the whole class "printer" as a single listview item into a single column.  I know I can access individual strings via `_printerlist[i].Hostname.ToString();` as well. 
The relevant layout of my class is shown below.

```
List<Printer> _printerlist = new List<Printer>();
public class Printer
{
    public string Hostname { get; set; }
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }


    public Printer() // this is a method within the Printer class
    {
        Hostname = string.Empty;
        Manufacturer = string.Empty;
        Model = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

I'm getting really close with this short code snippet below, but I need to be able to add 2 items.

```
for(int i=0; i<_printerlist.Count; i++)
{lstViewPrinters.Items.Add(_printerlist[i].Hostname).SubItems.Add(_printerlist[i].Manufacturer);}
```

Is the best method to go about this to just make it a range and delete the doubled up column?  Another method I saw was to add items with the `item1.SubItems.Add("SubItem1a");` command but I have my system in a `for` loop so I can't do that (or at least I don't know how, if someone can direct me to declaring `ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem("Something");` in a loop with changing names (item1) I'd be grateful as well.)

Could I get suggestions as to how I can add the class/list straight to the listview? Or how I should restructure my class, if that's a better solution.  Any general naming convention notes as well as links to other helpful links would be appreciated as well.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ListViewItem has a bunch of constructors, you can add all the properties in the new statement like this

```
var _printerlist = new List<Printer>();

for (int i = 0; i < _printerlist.Count; i++)
{
    lstViewPrinters.Items.Add(
        new ListViewItem(new[]
        {
            _printerlist[i].Hostname,
            _printerlist[i].Manufacturer,
            _printerlist[i].Model
        }));
}
```

Or for fun, you can do the entire thing in one statement with LINQ

```
_printerlist.ForEach(p => lstViewPrinters.Items.Add(
    new ListViewItem(new[]
    {
        p.Hostname,
        p.Manufacturer,
        p.Model
    })));
```

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks for your help.  Time to go back and look at constructors again since I clearly do not understand them well enough.