# How to add items on listview (each column)

Tags: c#, database, vb.net, listview

I tried using this code to add items on ListView but clearly I only add one column on each rows although I have 10 columns. Here's my code:

```
ListView1.Items.Add(firstname.Text)
ListView1.Items.Add(middlename.Text)
ListView1.Items.Add(lastname.Text)
ListView1.Items.Add(gender.Text)
ListView1.Items.Add(age.Text)
ListView1.Items.Add(address.Text)
ListView1.Items.Add(lrnNumber.Text)
ListView1.Items.Add(formerschool.Text)
ListView1.Items.Add(strandcourse.Text)
ListView1.Items.Add(contact.Text)
ListView1.Items.Add(birthdate.Text)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# listView, how do I add items to columns 2, 3 and 4 etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473148/c-sharp-listview-how-do-i-add-items-to-columns-2-3-and-4-etc)

Comment: you should pass an object to you listview, create a class containing all object and then instanciate it as observablecollection then populate your list

Answer (score 2):

You should create the object `ListViewItem` at first:

```cs
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(new []{"1","2","3","4"});
listView1.Items.Add(item);
```